# Binding issue with button hosted in 2 controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Hi I know this is alot of code but I'm hoping someone can help or point me in the right direction my export to csv command isn't firing even when using breakpoints on the command and task so I assume it can't be found in the data context somwhere, everything else works the data gets populated, edit button works.
So I have 2 `UserControl`s `TitleControl` and `BillOfMaterialsControl`, I have some buttons hosted in the title control where this is hosted in the bill of materials control, it seems my buttons are not working with being hosted in another control.

I'm getting this error in the output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ExportButtonCommand' property not found on 'object' ''TitleControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=ExportButtonCommand; DataItem='TitleControl' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

BillOfMaterials.xaml Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Bright_Instruments.Controls.BillOfMaterialsControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bright_Instruments.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Bright_Instruments.Controls"
         xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <controls:TitleControl Grid.Column="0" Badge="{Binding Badge, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Text="PARTS LIST" Icon="{iconPacks:PicolIcons Kind=ListNumbered}">
        <controls:TitleControl.TitleContent>
            <StackPanel Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button ToolTip="Print parts list" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Chromeless}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconEntypo Kind="Print"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>

                <Button Margin="5" 
                        Command="{Binding ExportButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="Export parts list to .csv" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Chromeless}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="FileCsvSolid"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>

                <Button Margin="5" ToolTip="Export parts list to .pdf" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Chromeless}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="FilePdfSolid"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:TitleControl.TitleContent>
    </controls:TitleControl>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Margin="0, 5, 5, 5" 
            Command="{Binding EditButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
            Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Flat}" 
            Content="EDIT"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding BillOfMaterials, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ChildItem.PartNumber}" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconFontAwesome Kind="WrenchSolid" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="PART NUMBER"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ChildItem.Description}" Width="*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterialDesign Kind="Description" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="DESCRIPTION"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>

                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ChildItem.Location}" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterialDesign Kind="LocationOn" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="LOCATION"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ChildItem.Quantity}" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Numeric" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="QUANTITY IN STOCK"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Numeric" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="QUANTITY REQ"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Flat}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                Command="{Binding ViewButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Content="VIEW"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconTypicons Margin="5" Kind="Eye"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="VIEW" Margin="5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

BillOfMaterials.cs Control

```
public partial class BillOfMaterialsControl : UserControl
{
    public BillOfMaterialsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Badge
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(BadgeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BadgeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BadgeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Badge", typeof(string), typeof(BillOfMaterialsControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public ICommand ViewButtonCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ViewButtonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewButtonCommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewButtonCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ViewButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BillOfMaterialsControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand ExportButtonCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ExoportButtonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExoportButtonCommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExoportButtonCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ExportButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BillOfMaterialsControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public ICommand EditButtonCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(EditButtonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditButtonCommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditButtonCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "EditButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BillOfMaterialsControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public List<BillOfMaterial> BillOfMaterials
    {
        get { return (List<BillOfMaterial>)this.GetValue(BillOfMaterialsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BillOfMaterialsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BillOfMaterialsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "BillOfMaterials", typeof(List<BillOfMaterial>), typeof(BillOfMaterialsControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

TitleControl.xaml Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Bright_Instruments.Controls.TitleControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bright_Instruments.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">

<Grid Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="5" Content="{Binding Icon}" 
                          TextBlock.Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}" />
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent" 
            Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}" 
            Padding="5"/>

        <Controls:Badged BadgePlacementMode="TopRight" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Badge="{Binding Badge}">
            <Controls:Badged.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Controls:Badged">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Badge" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Controls:Badged.Style>
        </Controls:Badged>
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TitleContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <Rectangle Height="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.AccentBase}">

    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

TitleControl.cs Control

```
public partial class TitleControl : UserControl
{
    public TitleControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Text", typeof(string), typeof(TitleControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Badge
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(BadgeProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(BadgeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BadgeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Badge", typeof(string), typeof(TitleControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public PackIconBase Icon
    {
        get { return (PackIconBase)this.GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Icon", typeof(PackIconBase), typeof(TitleControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object TitleContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TitleContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "TitleContent", typeof(object), typeof(TitleControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

My view where the bill of materials control is hosted

```
<controls:BillOfMaterialsControl
            EditButtonCommand="{Binding EditPartsListCommand}"
            Badge="{Binding PartsListCount}"
            ViewButtonCommand="{Binding ViewPartsListItemCommand}"
            ExportButtonCommand="{Binding ExportPartsListToCsvCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            BillOfMaterials="{Binding BillOfMaterials, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Views ViewModel

```
public ICommand ExportPartsListToCsvCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(ExportPartsListToCsv);

public async Task ExportPartsListToCsv()
{
    
    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

    var filter = $"CSV (*.csv) | *.csv";

    saveFileDialog.Filter = filter;
    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".csv";
    saveFileDialog.FileName = "Inventory.csv";
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            await CsvService.Write<BillOfMaterial>(saveFileDialog.FileName, BillOfMaterials);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BillOfMaterialsControl` uses a `TitleControl` control that in turn contains a `Button` that binds the `ExportButtonCommand` (which is a property in `BillOfMaterialsControl`) as command. Here, you use an relative source binding with ancestor type `UserControl` in it.

```
Command="{Binding ExportButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Picture the visual tree similiar to this (only with the essential parts in it).

- `BillOfMaterialsControl`

  - `TitleControl`

    - `Button`

The relative source binding will search up the visual tree to find a control of type `UserControl`. Both of your controls derive from `UserControl` and the first one found is `TitleControl`, but this control does not contain a property called `ExportButtonCommand` and that is the binding failure that you get.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ExportButtonCommand' property not found on 'object' ''TitleControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=ExportButtonCommand; DataItem='TitleControl' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

You could solve this issue in one of these ways.

- Modify the binding to use the concrete type of your control `BillOfMaterialsControl` as ancestor type. This way `TitleControl` does not match.

  ```
  Command="{Binding ExportButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:BillOfMaterialsControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  ```
- Specify a suitable [`AncestorLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestorlevel?view=net-5.0) to skip controls in the search process.

  ```
  Command="{Binding ExportButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  ```

  A value of `2` should work (if not, adapt it). From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestorlevel?view=net-5.0) on `AncestorLevel`:

  > Gets or sets the level of ancestor to look for, in FindAncestor mode. Use 1 to indicate the one nearest to the binding target element.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I used AncestorLevel 2 and this solved my problem specifying the actual type didnt work for some reason but the 2nd option did